# Clustering restaurant dishes

Tags: clustering, natural-language, partitioning

I have data about restaurants, their dishes and customer's orders. Then I want to cluster dishes in restaurant's menu by customer order. So clusters will be dishes in order and criteria of similarity will be price, ingredients and location of restaurant where dish is served.

For example if there is a Americano coffee in the order so result will be all coffees of all restaurants no farther then 100 metres from user(for example), and no more expensive than ordered coffee.

Does it possible to do it? If not than why? Can I do it by k-means method?

Answer (score 0):

If you can encode your data as numeric variables suitable for a least squares optimization, then k-means is an option.

But it certainly won't work as a black box. *You* need to know what you are doing, and what you *need*. I don't hunk you have understood how to formalize your problem, so it is too early to choose a tool. Just dumping your data into an algorithm and hoping the desired result comes out is magic, not statistics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If it's not too much trouble, could you give me a clue how my data should be represented as numeric? For example, exact value for range 100 metres without "no more"?

Comment: No, because I don't know your data. I'm not even convinced you want clustering from your unclear description. You need to phrase your problem as a *math* equation.